# Get network statistics of Wi-Fi interface used by specific ssid in windows

Tags: winapi, network-programming

What is the best way to  get previous `Network Statistics` in `Windows` used by `Wi-Fi interface` when it is connected to specific `SSID`? Using any programming language.

Comment: Please clarify your problem. Do you know both interface name and ssid, or you first need to find out wifi interface by known ssid you're connected to? Is the wifi interface connected to that ssid at the moment you query data, or you need statistics from some previous connection(s) to that ssid? What kind of statistics do you need?

Comment: @Alex Use case: Assume, my PC has wifi interface called 'WLAN0'. My mobile's SSID is 'mymobile'. I want to find out how much data is received and sent through 'WLAN0' while it is connected to 'mymobile' in this month. Got it?

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot get that without some kind of special accounting software which runs all the time and gathers it for you. Windows simply doesn't persist that kind of information, and even within single session it doesn't differentiate statistics between SSIDs (only between protocols).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows does not store data usage details per SSID.